# Snowflake partitioning

Tags: group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, lag, partition, lead

I have records like below:

| login_id | login_type | login_name | login_timestamp | page_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | event | null | 2023-01-13 00:22:02.560 | 1 |
| 1 | event | null | 2023-01-13 00:22:02.634 | 1 |
| 1 | page | login | 2023-01-13 00:22:02.882 | 1 |
| 1 | event | login | 2023-01-13 00:22:02.929 | 1 |
| 1 | page | login | 2023-01-13 00:22:02.922 | 2 |
| 1 | event | login | 2023-01-13 00:22:02.962 | 2 |
| 1 | event | null | 2023-01-13 00:22:07.751 | 2 |
| 2 | event | null | 2023-01-13 00:24:02.560 | 1 |
| 2 | event | null | 2023-01-13 00:24:02.634 | 1 |
| 2 | page | login | 2023-01-13 00:24:02.882 | 1 |
| 2 | event | null | 2023-01-13 00:24:02.929 | 1 |
| 2 | event | login | 2023-01-13 00:24:02.962 | 1 |
| 2 | event | null | 2023-01-13 00:24:07.751 | 1 |
| 3 | page | login | 2023-01-13 00:26:02.882 | 1 |
| 3 | event | null | 2023-01-13 00:26:02.929 | 1 |
| 3 | page | login | 2023-01-13 00:26:02.949 | 2 |
| 3 | event | login | 2023-01-13 00:26:02.962 | 2 |
| 3 | event | null | 2023-01-13 00:26:07.751 | 2 |

I want a query to fetch output based on below conditions:

```
1) Need to fetch only login_name is null and login_type='event'
2) Need to partition based on login_id,page_id and fetch the count before and after for login_type='page' order by login_timestamp
```

For Example:
For the above records, the result should be like this:

| login_id | login_type | login_name | count_of_event_before_page | count_of_event_afer_page | page_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | event | null | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | event | null | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | event | null | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | event | null | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | event | null | 0 | 1 | 2 |

Can anyone please guide me on this?

Comment: Can you post the query you tried?

Comment: Please don’t post images, use editable text so that it can be copied if someone wants to try a solution

Answer (score 1):

As you want to fetch only the rows in which login_name is null and login_type is 'event', I declared them as literals in the projection. But of course, I considered this requirement when filtering the rows. Here is the query:

```
with add_changes as (    
     select login_id, login_type, login_name, 
     CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT( login_type = 'page' ) over ( partition by login_id order by login_timestamp) page_status
     from test_table
     where ( login_name is null and login_type='event' ) or (login_type = 'page')
 )
select login_id, 'event' login_type, null login_name, count_if(page_status = 0) count_of_event_before_page,
count_if( page_status = 2 ) count_of_event_afer_page
from add_Changes
group by login_id
order by login_id;
```

Here is the result:

```
+----------+------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
| LOGIN_ID | LOGIN_TYPE | LOGIN_NAME | COUNT_OF_EVENT_BEFORE_PAGE | COUNT_OF_EVENT_AFER_PAGE |
+----------+------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
|        1 | event      | null       |                          2 |                        1 |
|        2 | event      | null       |                          2 |                        2 |
+----------+------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this conditional_change_event function, got some clarity now. But I missed one more scenario. I edited my question. Can you please review and guide me?